# Why children entities are duplicated in DB everytime i save parent object

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I have entities "ZakladProdukcyjny" and "MiejsceProwadzeniaDzialnosci".
There is an unidirectional relation @OneToMany with a join table.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinTable(name = "ZAKLAD_PRODUKCYJNY_MIEJSCE_PROWADZENIA_DZIALALNOSCI",
           joinColumns = {
              @JoinColumn(name = "zakladProdukcyjny_ID")},
           inverseJoinColumns = {
              @JoinColumn(name = "miejsceProwadzeniaDzialalnosci_ID")})
   private List<MiejsceProwadzeniaDzialalnosci> miejscaProwadzeniaDzialalnosci = new ArrayList<>();
```

I am using Spring JPARepositories

```
public interface ZakladProdukcyjnyRepository extends JpaRepository<ZakladProdukcyjny, Long>,
```

Everytime i am saving the parent entity with `zakladProdukcyjnyRepository.save(zakladProdukcyjny)`, children entities are being persised into DB so everytime save is executed on the JPARepository i am having duplicated entries.

The child entity uses a lombok for generating equals and hashcode.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public class MiejsceProwadzeniaDzialalnosci extends BaseEntity {
```

I have no idea what may be wrong here.

Comment: Did you try setting a cascade operation? Maybe you should try `CascadeType.ALL`

Comment: What hibernate version are you using?

Comment: The cascade was there i have deleted it during tests .hibernate version is: 5.3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should have beed fixed long time ago:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5855

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6776

Try changing the `List` to a `Set` or remove `CascadeType.ALL` and leave just `CascadeType.MERGE`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it hasn't helped. After changing to Set a result is the same.  Without the CascadeType.MERGE childrens aren't persisted in DB well and removing CascadeType.ALL may be problematic because i am getting Transient Object is not saved exception. It's probably because i am using Jparepository interface without entitymanager and without cascade PERSIST i would have to change my code quite a bit how i am saving my objects.

Comment: When it doesnt work with a Set then ditch Lombok, cause probably equals and hashCode are wrong. When he's complaining about the transient object then try to save MiejsceProwadzeniaDzialalnosci separately and then add the saved instance to the list. Also consider getting rid of the JoinTable. In OneToMany this is not neccesary.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. The issue was an equals functionality. Somewhere in the code i had:

```
    for (MiejsceProwadzeniaDzialalnosci mpd : uaktualnioneMiejscaProwadzeniaDzialalnosciZBDO) {
        if (!(zaklad.getMiejscaProwadzeniaDzialalnosci().contains(mpd))) {
            zaklad.getMiejscaProwadzeniaDzialalnosci().add(mpd);
        }
    }
```

after ovveriding the equals  method there is no duplicates.